# How to Move status bar along with the animation of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to do animation for `UINavigationController` using `CATransform3D` animation and also have to move the status bar along with the `UINavigationController`. Can status bar be moved without using snapshot?

I had tried using snapshot but I need to move original status bar along with the `UINavigationController`

I know some UIViewController properties like `transitioningDelegate`,`modalPresentationStyle` and `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance`. But I don't know how to use these properties to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack for this would be to hide the status bar without animation, but at the same time take a snapshot of the status bar as a UIView. Than you can animate it in whichever way you want.